# Como usar o rightclick Api google Maps para celular

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google

Hoje adicionei um evento para o meu mapa, no caso, se clicar com o botão direito do mouse, realiza determinado evento. Estou sem celular para testar.

Mas celular não possuí botão direito. A api do google maps converte este evento em que? Como o usuário vai realizar este evento?

```
 map.data.addListener('rightclick', function(event) {
```